# Google DataFlow Examples: Exception in Wordcount Execution

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to execute Google DataFlow WordCount sample in eclipse, but when I run, I've the next error, could anyone help me please?. I'm new on Google Cloud DataFlow.

I've already installed SDK's and configured my account.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Users/REYESRDR/.m2/repository/org/apache/beam/beam-runners-direct-java/2.5.0/beam-runners-direct-java-2.5.0.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
nov 08, 2019 1:52:46 P. M. org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource getEstimatedSizeBytes
INFO: Filepattern gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt matched 1 files with total size 157283
nov 08, 2019 1:52:46 P. M. org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource split
INFO: Splitting filepattern gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt into bundles of size 39320 took 121 ms and produced 1 files and 4 bundles
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManager.get(DoFnLifecycleManager.java:61)
 org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluatorFactory.createEvaluator(ParDoEvaluatorFactory.java:124)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluatorFactory.forApplication(ParDoEvaluatorFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformEvaluatorRegistry.forApplication(TransformEvaluatorRegistry.java:178)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_core.net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Initializable$Unavailable.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:334)
    at 
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Have you tried this with Java 8? In Java 9+, reflection is much more limited.

Comment: I think you've stepped in it.  :-)

Since the actual exception is "Cannot define class using reflection: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe" I suspect that it was trying to make for you some error about something you're doing being unsafe, but then it failed in trying to make the error for you.  When error handling code gets errors, you often want to pull your hair out.  I suggest debugging in to find out what the real error was in your code that it was trying to inform you was unsafe.